# PhoneGap 2.2.0 Android - Unable to open links in DroidGap WebView

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I would like to open links in the same droidgap web view but not able to accomplish.

Solutions that I have tried already are..

---

In Android you can make external links to open inside the webview by setting

`super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);`

---

`<access origin="www.google.com"/>`

to the phonegap.xml file.

Comment: All android versions? There is an issue in android 4.1

Comment: This may to be this Issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318703/access-control-allow-origin-error-at-android-4-1

Comment: Check out the ChildBrowser plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach tried 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I believe you need the protocol on the origin property.  So it should be

```
<access origin="http://www.google.com" />
```