# Phonegap on Android XmlHttpRequest Works in Emulator & browser, Not on Device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm stuck. My XmlHttpRequests are not working when I test on my device, but they do work perfectly in the emulator and in my browser.

Also I have added the domain to my whitelist. The really weird part is that it was working perfectly fine on the device yesterday too. Any ideas? I'm brand new to phone apps and phonegap.

```
<!--
    access elements control the Android whitelist.
    Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise
     -->

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="http://*.mydomain.com" />Code not neede
```

-------------- edit ----------------

I'm not sure why, or what happened. After playing around some more I changed.

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
<access origin="http://*.mydomain.com" />
```

to

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

The problem still existed. Just to try it I closed eclipse and then re-opnened it to run the app again and it worked. I'm thinking eclipse needs to be restarted after a change to the config.xml file.

Comment: Which android version? Some logs in the ADB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error At Android 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318703/access-control-allow-origin-error-at-android-4-1)
The (not accepted but highvoted) answer may solve the problem.

There was an issue at cordova: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1101

Comment: Thank you =0) It was driving me insane!