# jQuery Mobile + Phonegap on Android - no Ajax

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile

EDIT: Solution for JQuery Mobile + Phonegap AJAX Problems:

`subdomains="true"` property in config.xml is **not working in phonegap 2.9.0**, every request to a subdomain will return 200 but $.ajax won't fire the success function (and $.getJSON won't fire anyways).
Also: Syntax `*.domain.tld` as stated in the official doc is **not** working, only way I found to solve that problem: Setting access origin and acces uri to `"*"` (all)

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access uri="*"/>
```

---

I'm working on a mobile application using the jQuery Mobile Framework and Phonegap.
I've just added an AJAX request to my application which is used to get data from my webserver.
The page is correctly loading but Android (4.1.2) never fires the AJAX event or never gets a request from the Webserver, in fact it's just hanging on the loading spinner.

Strange thing about this is, that I already use an AJAX request to the same server (but with different domain) that works perfectly fine:

```
$.getJSON("[...]checkupdate.php?callback=?", function(data){    
   [...]    
})
```

I've tried to do the second request with $.getJSON too and it worked on my computer but failed on Android. I started looking around for a solution and found out, that setting the cache to false in $.ajax might help so I rewrote my code but it's still not working.

```
$.ajax({
cache : false,
type: 'GET',
url: requestURL,
dataType: 'jsonp',
context: document.body,
success: function(data){
    [...]
}});
```

Is there anything else to do to get this to work?

Comment: http://bit.ly/124oJ3U

Comment: @Selvin forgot to write that, I've already set the correct overrides. ($.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages and $.support.cors), disabled cache in request, whitelistet the domain in config.xml (and I'm using JSONP) anythig else I've missed?

Comment: ok ... so one more thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318703/access-control-allow-origin-error-at-android-4-1

Comment: Isn't this only needed if I use local files to send the request? Besides that, I'm really wondering why the exactly same code is working a few lines below...

Comment: ideas: 1. Take a look at logout output for clues. 2. you might want to process the ajax complete callback to know if something went wrong (or if the ajax call was actually processed).

Comment: @kctang I've completed it and getting the Error: %callbackfunction% was not called (readyState = 4, status = parsererror [200])

Comment: @all Edited my post, setting access origin and access uri solved the problem...

Comment: you should probably post your answer using "answer your own question" otherwise it will keep showing up as "unanswered" in stackoverflow.

Comment: Really shoud do that, I was hoping someone would correct me and say that it's just a bad dream but it really looks like this bug was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve that problem. I noticed, that the `subdomains="true"` property in phonegap's config.xml is not working. (Phonegap 2.9.0). Every request to a **subdomain** will return status 200 but `$.ajax` won't fire the success function (and `$.getJSON` won't fire anyways). The syntax `*.domain.tld` as stated in the official doc isn't working for me either, only way I found to solve that problem was setting access origin and acces uri to `"*"` (all)